# Display data of the logged user in mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I am trying to display the details of the currently logged user. For that I am using ADO.Net to fetch the data from the database.

In my database, I have 2 tables with `Employeedetails` and with `Taskdetails`. And maintaining relationship via the `email id` column which exists in both tables.

This is my controller:

```
string sql = "SELECT TaskDetail.id ,TaskDetail.ProjectID ,TaskDetail.ProjectName  ,TaskDetail.StartDate ,TaskDetail.EstimatedDate,TaskDetail.TaskDescription,TaskDetail.Email FROM TaskDetail INNER JOIN tblEmployee ON TaskDetail.email = tblEmployee.email where  tblEmployee.Email='" + email + "'"; 

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

var Details = new List<TaskDetails>();
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        var ProjectDetail = new TaskDetails();
                        ProjectDetail.ProjectID = rdr["ProjectID"].ToString();
                        ProjectDetail.ProjectName = rdr["ProjectName"].ToString();
                        ProjectDetail.StartDate = DateTime.Parse(rdr["StartDate"].ToString());
                        ProjectDetail.EstimatedDate = DateTime.Parse(rdr["EstimatedDate"].ToString());
                        ProjectDetail.TaskDescription = rdr["TaskDescription"].ToString();
                        Details.Add(ProjectDetail);
                    }
                }

return View(Details);
```

This is my model:

```
    public class TaskDetails
    {
        public string ProjectID { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EstimatedDate { get; set; }
        public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my view:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>TaskDetails</title>
</head>
<tbody>
@foreach (var ProjectDetail in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@ProjectDetail.ProjectID</td>
        <td>@ProjectDetail.ProjectName</td>
        <td>@ProjectDetail.StartDate</td>
        <td>@ProjectDetail.EstimatedDate</td>
        <td>@ProjectDetail.TaskDescription</td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

Here my requirement is to display the detials of the current logged user. Is my Select stament is correct..?? and how to display the details based on the logged user...

Comment: have your `Employeedetails` and `Taskdetails` tables is in one to one relationship or one to many it seems like one to many.. secondly where you stuck what's the issue is your query not work as you expected or data not bind in view? can you please elaborate more about you issue?

Comment: Binding data to view is fine..data is coming but the all the user's data is coming. But I need to display the current user only..

Comment: you have passed  email in where condition `tblEmployee.Email='" + email + "'` is your logged in user's email  ? make sure is it that email which you wants

Comment: yes its session email..current user's email id